# Getting "set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons" when importing a CSV file into contacts

Tags: wordpress, php

I'm getting "set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons"  when importing a CSV file into my contacts.

The exact warning is "set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/clients/9f584f50407ada97b7c17ed3b0bbc0f0/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Controller.php on line 31"

I use CiviCRM v5.21.0 under WP last version

Any idea will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case has been solved in adding this two lines in the wp_config.php file after the define section:

*ini_set('display_errors','Off');*

*ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );*

It is also important to solve it because it can have consequences for CiviCRM (for us in the import process).
Hope this helps